# sql - sum columns from same table having multiple unique ids

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, reporting-services

I  would like to sum 3 columns from the same table based on three unique id.

```
If id="1" sum(area1) 
If id="2" sum(area2)
if id="3" sum(area3)
```

Table data:

```
id area1 area2 area3
1   10     2    10
1    1     10    10
2    1     10    10
3    1     10    10
3  10     2     10
```

Output should be:

id1= 43 id2 = 21 id3 = 43

```
Select houseID, sum(area1), b.sum(area2), c.sum(area3) FROM table1, table1 b, table1 c
WHERE table1.id="1" or b.id = "2" or c.id="3"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

Considering that you edited your output, you have to do:

```
select Id, sum(area1 + area2 + area3) as 'Sum'
from yourTable
--where id in (1,2,3) if you have more id's and just want those
group by Id
```

Comment: Corrected my output example. Its based on ID, so I cant just sum the columns. Sorry about the mistake in my post.

Comment: THat did  it! thanks. Have to wait another 2 minutes to accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select houseID, 
       sum(IF id = 1 THEN area1 ELSE 0 END) as [a],
       sum(IF id = 2 then area2 ELSE 0 END) as [b],
       sum(IF id = 3 then area3 ELSE 0 END) as [c]
FROM table1
WHERE id in (1,2,3) -- not needed might be faster
```